# Android - RecyclerView in sync with storage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I am facing a very peculiar problem. I am creating an e-commerce application. I can set quantity of articles using a EditText. Actually, EditText is part of a widget which has two buttons to decrease and increase quantity. Reference screenshot is given below.

[image]

Behind this RecyclerView, there is a basket data structure that keeps track of the quantity of each article that has been selected. So even when context comes back to this fragment, same quantity is shown in recyclerview.

So whenever EditText of some card is changed value is updated into the basket by a listener(TextWatcher) on EditText. But RecyclerView has this behaviour of recycling item views so the value of text is set to some other value as the card moves out and the listener gets called because of that.

I want to avoid listener calling when text changes happen because of RecyclerView. But I have no idea about how to get it done.

**Edited to add code**

Code for CountWidget:

```
private void init(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CountWidget, 0, 0);
        max = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.CountWidget_max, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        min = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.CountWidget_min, 0);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.count_widget, this, true);

    final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);

    minusButton = (ImageView) container.getChildAt(0);
    countView = (EditText) container.getChildAt(1);
    plusButton = (ImageView) container.getChildAt(2);

    countView.setText(Integer.toString(min));
    countView.setCursorVisible(true);

    minusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hideKeypad(context);
            String countText = countView.getText().toString();
            int count = min;
            if (!countText.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    count = Integer.parseInt(countText);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    count = min;
                }
            }
            if (count > min) count--;
            countView.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            if (onButtonClickListener != null) {
                onButtonClickListener.OnMinusButtonClick(count);
            }
        }
    });

    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hideKeypad(context);
            String countText = countView.getText().toString();
            int count = max;
            if (!countText.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    count = Integer.parseInt(countText);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    count = min;
                }
            }
            if (count < max) count++;
            countView.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            if (onButtonClickListener != null) {
                onButtonClickListener.OnPlusButtonClick(count);
            }
        }
    });

    countView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private int previousCount;
        private int currentCount;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 0 || !isNumber(String.valueOf(charSequence))) {
                previousCount = 0;
            } else {
                previousCount = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(charSequence));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 0 || !isNumber(String.valueOf(charSequence))) {
                currentCount = 0;
            } else {
                currentCount = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(charSequence));
            }
            if (currentCount == previousCount) return;
            if (onCountChangeListener != null) {
                // value is updated into basket
                onCountChangeListener.onCountChange(currentCount);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

Code for RecyclerView.Adapter :

```
@Override
public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.article_list_row, parent, false);
    return new ArticleViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Article article = articles.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(article.getName());
    viewHolder.counter.setCount(basket.getQuantity(article.getId()));

    viewHolder.counter.setOnCountChangeListener(new CountWidget.OnCountChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCountChange(int count) {
            basket.add(article.getId(), count);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articles.size();
}

/**
 * Article row view holder.
 */
public static class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public CountWidget counter;

    public ArticleViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_name);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_thumbnail);
        counter = (CountWidget) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u add the code

Comment: by textWatcher listener insert value in database so that it wont change u cant stop recyclerview listener

Comment: @siddhesh, how shall I identify if the value is changed using keypad or by recyclerview?

Comment: use addTextChangedListener it has override methods you ll get it

Comment: @VV help yourself with the code.